# Custom theme conflicts with menu

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to add a drop down menu on my Wordpress website. I have a custom theme made by somebody I can no longer get in contact with. When I make a Page a sub-unit in the Menu section of the Wordpress admin area, it doesn't make that page a drop down. Instead, it just makes that page appear under what is supposed to be the parent. Any help is much appreciated. Here is the code for my menu:

```
<div class="navigation">
<?php 
wp_nav_menu(array( 'menu'=>'main-menu','items_wrap'=>'<ul class="menu">%3$s</ul>')); 
?>              
</div>
```

Comment: I get server not found from the link

Comment: @mlegg Sorry, I spelled jewelry incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The way your menu will behave will depend on how the theme and wordpress installed is configured. You will have to analyze the template and understand what it is doing and how it is rendering your menu.

Most of the times, the menu is hardcoded in the "index.php" page that is in the folder: "wp-content\themes\themename\"

Check there how the menu is build.

Comment: @JeanAdamCalixtio there is no information on how to menu is built in index.php. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: it can be in functions.php too as an action  but I didnt get your question well if its a javascript conflict or what?Can u paste also navigation class codes from your css stylesheet?

Comment: @Gazi       
{ margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; font-size: 100%; vertical-align: baseline; background: transparent; display: block; }